# The purpose of このよう な

Tags: meaning

マイク は たくさん の 友好的 な 人たち と 会う こと が できます 。

マイク は このよう な（この様な） お客様 と 話し を する 時 幸せ に 感じます 。

In the above passage, I translate このよう な（この様な） お客様 と 話し を する as "this way of talking with customers." But "this way" is never explained. All the first sentence says is that Mike is able to meet a lot of nice people, it does not talk about the way he talks with customers.

Comment: Any reason for all the spaces in between the words? It will be better for you to get used to how japanese is written in real life, without those spaces. imo

Comment: And even when Japanese is written with spaces, such as in certain works aimed at children, there are usually far fewer than this. There is almost never a space between a particle and the noun it connects to, for example.

Comment: That is still far better than using romaji.

Comment: @AeonAkechi I copied and pasted from Lingq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 「マイク は たくさん の 友好的{ゆうこうてき} な 人たち と 会{あ}う こと が できます 。マイク は **このよう な**（この様な） お客様{きゃくさま} と 話{はな}し を する 時{とき} 幸{しあわ}せ に 感{かん}じます 。」

「このよう**な**」 functions **adjectivally** to modify a noun.

「このよう**に**」 functions **adverbially** to modify a verb or adjective.

Therefore, 「このよう**な**お客様」 means "***this type of customers***".  What type is that?  It is the 「友好的なお客様」 ("the friendly customers") as stated in the first sentence.  Are you following this?

So, "this way of talking with customers" is not being talked about here.

> "Mike can meet many friendly customers.  Mike feels happy when speaking to this type of customers."